# mPDF v8.0.4 - setProtection function it is not working as expected

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf

I´m trying to use the functionality of the function [setProtection()](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html).

1. I have the feeling that the generated file it´s not protected because I can copy and I can print the file content.

According with the documentation, every action of copy, print and etc should be **denied** for whom tries to manipulate the file after downloaded. [Example #1](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html)

```
// Encrypt the file and grant no permissions to the user to copy, print etc.
// The user will be able to open the file as no password is specified
// Owner cannot access full rights because no owner_password was set

$mpdf->SetProtection(array());
```

1. Am I using the function in the correct place in the file?
2. Is there some bug to fix in this method?
3. Is there an alternative solution outside the box that can someone use to protect the file that will be generated?
   An API ou something else?
4. As a PDF reader Tool I´m Evince V.2.32.0.145

This is the code: **Thank you so much.**

```
// Security method
$mpdf->SetProtection(array());

//$mpdf->SetProtection(array('print-highres'), '', 'test123456&&987%654', 128);

$mpdf->SetTitle("Quorum sine causa fieri nihil");
$mpdf->SetAuthor('Quorum sine causa fieri nihil');
$mpdf->SetCreator('Quorum sine causa fieri nihil');
$mpdf->SetSubject('Quorum sine causa fieri nihil');
$mpdf->SetKeywords('Quorum sine causa fieri nihil');

$css = file_get_contents(__DIR__. '/assets/css/mpdf.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS); // Load the CSS

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);// Load the html

// INVOICE name generated.
$fileName = 'Invoicename'.'_'.date('D-d-m-Y-H-i-s').'_'.$order_id.'.pdf';

$mpdf->Output($fileName,"D");

$mpdf->cleanup();
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to set the permission, user and password with the `SetProtection` function.

```
// Encrypt the file and grant no permissions to the user
// The user will need to use "UserPassword" to open the file
// Owner has full rights using the password "MyPassword"
$mpdf->SetProtection(array(), 'UserPassword', 'MyPassword');
```

Documentation here:

`https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html`

Comment: can you read this comment on the code comment line?
// Encrypt the file and grant no permissions to the user.
It does not make any sense to use this line of code!

Comment: @PaulodoPorto This will stop the user from copying and printing the document. Not sure if you give me the -1, if so, what is your solution?

Comment: Hello @Bossman.
After more than 8 hours trying to find the solution I can say. 
The point is that, the method setProtection is not working for me as described directly in question above.

Comment: 1° It does not make sense to block the file with password for any users.
2° Also it does not make any sense to give the owner as me full rights using password.
I see that you do not really read the question and is trying another thing that it does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry for trying to help. I can't see a PDF being protected without credentials, i could be wrong (more than likely). The only thing i can advise now is submitting an issue directly on github here: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf. Again, only trying to help.